# scripting openvpn client certificate creation without '-config' in windows console

Tags: batch-file, openvpn, openssl

Have set of windows batch scripts as an automatized environment. Trying to include openvpn client certificates generating into this environment. Got inspiration in EasyRSA 2.x which includes set of batch scripts assembling openssl.exe parameters to certificate generating hadling.

Wanna avoid usage of `-config file.cfg` for good reasons, and trying to write all necessary variables as a content of console `-config` parameter. According [third option here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37927291/using-openssl-alternate-config-file-from-bash/37943865#37943865) this should be possible but did not found any example and linked man page does not contain any syntax explanation and is linux oriented. Commands I want to script:

```
rem creating request for new certificate
"%HOME%\..\bin\openssl.exe" req -key rsa:2048 -days 3650 -nodes -keyout "%HOME%\keys\%NAME_CN%.key" -out "%HOME%\keys\%NAME_CN%.csr"  -subj "/C=%KEY_COUNTRY%/ST=%KEY_PROVINCE%/L=%KEY_CITY%/O=%KEY_ORG%/OU=%KEY_OU%/CN=%NAME_CN%" 

rem signing request by certification authority key, creating cert/key pair
"%HOME%\..\bin\openssl.exe" ca -days 3650 -cert -out "%HOME%\keys\%NAME_CN%.crt" -in "%HOME%\keys\%NAME_CN%.csr"

rem check if created client certificate is valid
"%HOME%\..\bin\openssl.exe" verify -CAfile "%HOME%\keys\%CA_CRT%.crt" -purpose sslclient "%HOME%\keys\%NAME_CN%.crt"
```

first two command give me following error:

```
Ignoring -days; not generating a certificate
Can't open /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf for reading, No such file or directory
2124:error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process:crypto/bio/bss_file.c:69:fopen('/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf','r'
)
```

As a total last resort I could create minimalistic cfg file with few well commented variables, all variables possible to be writen on command line should be there. Anyone could kick me to right direction please?

Comment: You must have a `openssl.cnf` file, but as you say it can be minimal.

Comment: Are you sure? Someone here https://security.stackexchange.com/a/198409 says `-config` option is no longer needed, but this talk is about `req -x509` If config file is REALLY still needed, could someone help me to create minimalistic one for my request? Spend _LOT_ if time with googling, but as I do not understand cryptography, many terms are still too strange for me.

Comment: Normally, the installation of OpenSSL installs a generic/default `openssl.cnf` file.  The trick in the answer you linked to was using command line options to override the values in the config file so that you don't need to edit it, or even know where it is.

Comment: so openssl always check for existence of config file, and this feature could not be turned off by providing all necessary options on commandline?

Comment: Another person here  http://securitypad.blogspot.com/2018/05/summary-you-need-openssl.html    says: "OpenSSL commands (that is, the ones invoked from the command line) are mostly controlled by their options. But in order to issue X.509 certificates or CSRs OpenSSL needs a configuration file" So this look like config file is needed only for SOME operations.

Comment: The commands which have a `-config` option expect a configuration file.  Both `ca` and `req` used in your question do have that option, so expect a configuration file.  The `verify` doesn't, so it does not require a configuration file.